# What arguments does MapBasic's ColumnInfo() take?

Tags: mapbasic

MapBasic's `tableInfo()` function has a [KnowledgeBase docs page here](http://testdrive.mapinfo.com/techsupp/miprod.nsf/c5f0c7263940a53d8525669b00568e6b/5e2299f890ab8b2585256a9a00587970?OpenDocument) listing the arguments and all the attributes it takes, and a usage example in the [reference document](http://reference.mapinfo.com/software/mapbasic/english/9_0/MB_UG.pdf).

`columnInfo()` has neither of these (that I can find). I can't find any docs for it anywhere, other than a passing mention in the reference docs confirming that it exists:

> The functions **TableInfo( )**, **ColumnInfo( )** and **NumTables( )** let you
>   determine information...
>
> - **ColumnInfo( )** returns information about a column in a table, such as
>     the column’s name, the  column’s data type, and whether the column is
>     indexed.

That's it. What arguments does it take (e.g. is it `columnInfo( nTabNum, nColNum, Attr )`? Or maybe `columnInfo( objColumn, Attr )`?) and what are the attribute names (e.g. are they named COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_INFO_NAME, TAB_INFO_COL_NAME... etc?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have look into MapBasic **Reference** Guide not just 'User Guide':):
http://reference.mapinfo.com/software/mapbasic/english/9_0/MB_Ref.pdf

---

**ColumnInfo( ) function**

Purpose
Returns information about a column in an open table. You can call this function from the MapBasic Window in MapInfo Professional.

**Syntax**

**ColumnInfo(** { *tablename* | *tablenum* } ,
{ *columnname* | "COLn"} , *attribute* **)**

*tablename* is a string representing the name of an open table.
*tablenum* is an integer representing the number of an open table.
*columnname* is the name of a column in that table.
*n* is the number of a column in the table.
*attribute* is a code indicating which aspect of the column to read.

**Return Value**
Depends on the attribute parameter specified.

**Description**

The **ColumnInfo( )** function returns information about one column in an open table.

The function's first parameter specifies either the name or the number of an open table. The second parameter specifies which column to query. The attribute parameter dictates which of the column's
attributes the function should return. The attribute parameter can be any value from this table.

[image]

etc,etc